# Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens on google service

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am trying to upload the file from local system to my gmail Google Drive. I have created the Google Service with my gmail account. Service account address generate by google is `ucxxx@ucxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. When i try to upload the file it show it is successfully uploaded but i can't see any file on Google drive.

Also when i pass my email address then it is giving error `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested`

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService GetService2()
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService.Scope.Drive };


        //"SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE";
        
        String serviceAccountEmail = "ucxxx@ucxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

        // Scope and user email id which you want to impersonate
        var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = scopes,
            User = "ucxxxxx@gmail.com" //// this is giving me error when i pass  actual gmail id but 
                                      ////when i pass ucxxx@ucxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com file 
                                     ///uploaded successfully but don't know where the file is uploading 
        };

        //get private key, from .JSON file
        //var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer.FromPrivateKey("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0B\ndQtio==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"));

        // Create the service.
        var service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "DriveAPI",
        });



        service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
        return service;
    }
```

I have read many articles from stackoverflow and other but not get a proper solution or may be i did not understand. Thanks for your comments and

Answer (score 1):

There's an actual page detailing all the [JWT Errors](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#error-codes) and possible solution, for your case you have:

> A service account was authorized using the client email address rather than the client ID (numeric) in the Admin console.

> In the [Domain-wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106) page in the Admin console, remove the client, and re-add it with the numeric ID.

---

Also from your post I deduced that you are using a plain *@gmail.com* account that doesn't involve a domain. From all the documentation I could find you need an organization and a [Google Workspace Account](https://workspace.google.com/) to set up a [Domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

Answer (score 0):

> Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested

Normally means that you are trying to use `ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer` with invalid service account email address in your case i suspect it may have to do with the fact that your not loading the FromCertificate

I recommend using the following code and passing it the full creetinals.json file you downloaded from Google developer console.  Make sure that you have actually [created service account credentials](https://youtu.be/asrCdWFrF0A) and not another type of credentials and this is the file you are using.  Also be sure to enable the Google drive api.

```
const string serviceAccount = "XXX@XXX.com";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2("cred.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var gsuiteUser = "user@yourdomain.com";

        var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount)
        {
            User = gsuiteUser,
            Scopes = new string[] { Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService.Scope.Drive };
 }

        }.FromCertificate(certificate);


  // Create the  Analytics service.
  return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
          {
          HttpClientInitializer = credential,
          ApplicationName = "Drive Service account Authentication Sample",
           });
```